# how can i measure more than 16 digits after zero with python?

Tags: python, printing, digits

i want to measure about 1000 digits after zero of a number, but i don't know what to do with it to print all of the numbers because it just prints the first 16 numbers
what should i do to have them all printed?
i tried to change it to string but the problem is that this big number is made by a bigger number which should be the denominator and another problem is that this number is sum of an iterator and i cannot change it to string in each step
i tried to make it a product of 10 for example 10^10 or bigger but it didnt answer and it just printed 17 numbers

this is the code:

```
S=0
for k in range(n+1):
    S+=((factorial(6*k))*(13591409+545140134*k))/((factorial(3*k))*((factorial(k))**3)*((-640320)**(3*k)))
X=((426880*((10005)**0.5))/S)
print(X)
```

Comment: whoa.  This: `.` is a period.  It separates lexical groupings we call "sentences" from one another.  Please utilize it.

Comment: Python floating point numbers use IEEE 754 representation, which allows for 53 bits, which is 15-17 digits when all is said and done.  You likely need a much larger number library to do these calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 100              #Set precision
>>> decimal.Decimal('22') / decimal.Decimal('7')  
Decimal('3.142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857143')
```

Comment: Or maybe [`fractions`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html), if all the numbers are rational and exact answers really matter.

Comment: i tried fractions but the answers were the same, it didn't answer right